# Navigation bar won't appear after push

Tags: swift

I have a login and home Viewcontrollers, after moving from the loginVC to homeVC, the navigation bar is hidden, I tried few things but nothing worked.. This is how I move from login to home:

```
func handleLogin() {
    guard let email = self.mView.emailTxtField.text else { return }
    guard let pass = self.mView.passTxtField.text else { return }
    Service.shared.loginUser(email, pass) { (answer) in
        if answer == true {

            UserDefaults.standard.set(Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid, forKey:     USER_UID_KEY)
            let vc = HomeVC(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())

            let transition = CATransition()
            transition.duration = 0.5
            transition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: .easeInEaseOut)
            transition.type = .push
            transition.subtype = .fromTop
            self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

        }else {
            //TODO: SHOW ERROR
            print("CAN'T LOGIN ....")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your home view controller calling `navigationController.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)`

Comment: @Rudedog No. Even exiting and returning to the app (after we saved that the user is logged in) the navigation bar is showing.

Answer (score 1):

You must hide navigation Bar when Login VC will apper, hide when will disapper.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: animated)
}
```